# Django: how to do a group by on a field that is an indexed varchar?

Tags: django, orm

I have a model `Product` like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    product_model = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
```

The field `manufacturer` is not a primary key, but it's an index. I would like to do a query that group all the products by `manufacturer`.

Something like: `Product.objects.all().group_by(manufacturer)`.

(This is for use in Django Rest Framework where I have to return an array of `manufacturer` and for each `manufacturer`, an array of all the `Product`'s of the `manufacturer`).

How would yo do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 2 different models? One for the manufacturer and one for the product and link them using a ForeignKey.

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer',
                                     related_name='products',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

manufacturer = Manufacturer.objects.first()

manufactorer.products.all()  # Gives you all products for that specific manufacturer
```

Comment: I can't touch the models, they're not mine... sorry